# Why does my SQL Statement not SUM() up correctly?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following statement:

```
SELECT 
   ROUND(SUM(invoicetitle.unitpricegross*invoicetitle.suppliedquantity),2) as Costs,
   SUM(invoicetitle.suppliedquantity) AS Unitamounts 
FROM invoicetitle 
WHERE 
  ((SELECT invoice.state 
    FROM invoice where invoicetitle.invoiceid = invoice.invoiceid 
     and (invoice.invoicedate >= 1609459200000 and invoice.invoicedate <= 1640908800000)) = (1 or 4)) 
GROUP BY invoicetitle.invoicetitle_number
```

note that `= (1 or 4)` refers to two statements in the database where 1 is sold and 4 is a refund.

With `= (1))` I get the following results:

Costs    -    Unitamounts
3.281,10  -    582

With `= (4))` I get the following results:

Costs    -    Unitamounts
-115,2   -    -32

With `= (1 or 4))` I get the following results:

Costs    -    Unitamounts
3.281,10  -    582

But **I expect** as a correct SUM() of it:

Costs    -    Unitamounts
3.165,9  -    550

What am I doing wrong that the results are not subtracted correctly?

Comment: use IsNull (field,0) to check for null.  The subquery looks strange.  use the where exists instead

Comment: Change `= (1 or 4)` to `IN (1,4)`, see [IN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_in)

Comment: What is happening is the expression `(1 OR 4)` is being evaluated as boolean (true) so the return value is 1.   Consider `SELECT (3 OR 4)` returns `1`.  The expression  `foo = (3 OR 4)` is equivalent to `foo = 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably meant to do:

```
SELECT 
   ROUND(SUM(invoicetitle.unitpricegross*invoicetitle.suppliedquantity),2) as Costs,
   SUM(invoicetitle.suppliedquantity) AS Unitamounts 
FROM invoicetitle 
INNER JOIN invoice ON invoicetitle.invoiceid = invoice.invoiceid 
          and (invoice.invoicedate BETWEEN 1609459200000 
                                      and  1640908800000)
WHERE invoice.state IN (1,4)
GROUP BY invoicetitle.invoicetitle_number
```

Comment: thank you  this helped me a lot